# django-import-export buttons not correctly styled on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-import-export, django-suit

Django version: 1.9.7
Django Suit version: 0.2.19
Python version: 2.7.10

Issue:
I am using django-import-export in django-suit
I have my app deployed to heroku
When I run "heroku local" I have no issues
But when I view my admin pages on heroku, import-export are not appearing as buttons, but rather is list items

Here is the resulting page source running locally

```
<div id="content-main">
<div class="inner-center-column"> 
<div class="module filtered" id="changelist">
<div class="toolbar-content clearfix"> 
<div class="object-tools"> 
<a class="btn" href="import/" class="import_link">Import</a> 
<a class="btn" href="export/?" class="export_link">Export</a>
```

Here is the resulting page source running on heroku

```
<div id="content-main"> 
<div class="inner-center-column"> 
<div class="module filtered" id="changelist"> 
<div class="toolbar-content clearfix"> 
<ul class="object-tools">
<li><a href="import/" class="import_link">Import</a></li> 
<li><a href="export/?" class="export_link">Export</a></li>
```

The strange this is, that if I redeploy to heroku, intermittently it the problem goes away, but if the heroku dyno went to sleep and is woken up again, the problem re-appears

Comment: Is there any console errors when styles are missing?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how the code above is generated, e.g. is that from templates in your code? Can you also make sure that both install have exactly the same versions for django-import-export?

Comment: both versions of django-import-export are the same, and I am not able to see console errors or output on heroku

Comment: my suspicion is it has something to do with static files not being served - only thing that can explain how it just "fixes" itself after a restart/reinstall of some components